# how to display employee names starting with a and then b in sql

Tags: sql

i want to display the employee names which having names start with a and b ,it should be like list will display employees with  'a' as a first letter and then the  'b' as a first letter...

so any body tell me what is the command to display these...

Answer (score 39, accepted):

To get employee names starting with A or B listed in order...

```
select employee_name 
from employees
where employee_name LIKE 'A%' OR employee_name LIKE 'B%'
order by employee_name
```

If you are using Microsoft SQL Server you could use

```
....
where employee_name  LIKE '[A-B]%'
order by employee_name
```

This is not standard SQL though it just gets translated to the following which is.

```
WHERE  employee_name >= 'A'
       AND employee_name < 'C'
```

For all variants you would need to consider whether you want to include accented variants such as `Á` and test whether the queries above do what you want with these on your RDBMS and collation options.

Comment: its working but i want to display in alphabetical order like the names with a letter should be first and then the names with b letter

Comment: @lak in iphone: So what exactly are you trying to do? I mean, these answers are all pretty much the same, and from what I can understand from your question - correct. It sounds to me that you should either try doing some research on your own before asking the question or define the question better so we can help you.

Comment: In oracle we can use -                                                                                        
    select employee_name from employees where employee_name BETWEEN 'A' and 'B'; this one is also useful.

Answer (score 5):

```
select columns
  from table
 where (
         column like 'a%' 
      or column like 'b%' )
 order by column asc
```

Comment: we shall share in the glory :-)

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions work well if needing to find a range of starting characters.  The following finds all employee names starting with A, B, C or D and adds the “UPPER” call in case a name is in the database with a starting lowercase letter.  My query works in Oracle (I did not test other DB's).  The following would return for example:
Adams
adams
Dean
dean

This query also ignores case in the ORDER BY via the "lower" call:

```
SELECT employee_name 
FROM employees
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(UPPER(TRIM(employee_name)), '^[A-D]')
ORDER BY lower(employee_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select employee_name 
from employees
where employee_name LIKE 'A%' OR employee_name LIKE 'B%'
order by employee_name
```

Answer (score 0):

What cfengineers said, except it sounds like you will want to sort it as well.

```
select columns
  from table
 where (
         column like 'a%' 
      or column like 'b%' )
order by column
```

Perhaps it would be a good idea for you to check out some tutorials on SQL, it's pretty interesting.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking about alphabetical order the syntax is:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY column
```

the best example I can give without knowing your table and field names:

```
SELECT * FROM employees ORDER BY name
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with my suggestion? Why would it get a downvote?

Comment: It wasn't from me. I suspect it is because the question says that they want names starting with a and b and your answer doesn't handle that. I wouldn't be massively surprised though if it was to turn out that the question is badly worded and your interpretation is correct.

Comment: Precisely, I suspected the wording wasn't exactly right, and he was looking for alphabetical order, not strictly A and B names only in alphabetical order. If my interpretation is incorrect, it's incorrect, but you cant fault me for trying my best to answer someones question which isn't very easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from stores 
where name like 'a%' or 
name like 'b%' 
order by name
```

Comment: this will only work for names starting with a or b, you need to use the answer I posted to sort alphabetically A-Z

Answer (score 0):

```
select name_last, name_first
from employees
where name_last like 'A%' or name_last like 'B%'
order by name_last, name_first asc
```

Answer (score 0):

Here what I understood from the question is starting with "a " and then "b"
ex:

- abhay
- abhishek
- abhinav

So there should be two conditions and both should be true means you cant use "OR" operator
Ordered by is not not compulsory but its good if you use.

```
Select e_name from emp 
where  e_name like 'a%' AND e_name like '_b%'
Ordered by e_name
```

Answer (score 0):

From A to Z:

```
select employee_name from employees ORDER BY employee_name ;
```

From Z to A:

```
select employee_name from employees ORDER BY employee_name desc ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle:
Just felt to do it in different way. Disadvantage: It doesn't perform full index scan. But still gives the result and can use this in substring.

```
select employee_name 
from employees
where lpad(employee_name,1) ='A'
 OR lpad(employee_name,1) = 'B'
order by employee_name
```

We can use LEFT in SQL Server  instead of lpad . Still suggest not a good idea to use this method.

Answer (score 0):

We can also use REGEXP

```
select employee_name 
from employees
where employee_name REGEXP '[ab].*'
order by employee_name
```